# Dlls are too big. Is there a way to reduce dependencies size?

Tags: c++, dll, libtorch

I'm using libtorch in my c++ project and some dlls are extremely big. `torch_cuda_cu.dll 1374 mb`. `torch_cpu.dll 206 mb`. Is there a way to pull needed functions from these dll to bind them to project statically? Why are they so big how you supposed to use torch on devices?

Comment: The size comes from supporting many different CUDA versions. There is essentially code for your GPU to execute in there, in different versions in order to support a wide range of GPUs. If you can somehow limit your support to specific CUDA versions (thereby limiting which graphics cards you support) or you can get by without certain features such as MKL, you can reduce the size by compiling libtorch yourself with the relevant flags. See also: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34058

Comment: @CherryDT that makes more sense now! thank you for response!